# Rails 3.2 Fetching Objects in application controller before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, activerecord

I am trying to use a _before_filter_ in my `ApplicationController` to fetch a user object matching a `user_id` in a http parameter like:

```
before_filter :fetch_user

def fetch_user
  if params[:user_id].present?
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # user not found
end
```

This is working for me in all controllers which inherit from `ApplicationController` **except the controller which is called UsersController** in which `@user` seems to be set to `nil` in some way.

What could be the reason for this behavior? And is this the standard behavior? How to avoid/disable it?

**UPDATE:**

I always pass a parameter called `user_id` to the controller.
If I include the `exact same before filter` directly into the UsersController it is working!
there are no other before filters in the UsersController

**UPDATE 2:**

Route which is use to users controller

```
match ':user_id' => 'users#show'
```

User Controller code:

```
  def show
    if @user     
      render :text => "user not nil"
    else
      render :text => "user nil"
   end
  end
```

There is definitely a user with the id passed at the user_id parameter because

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's in UsersController ? Is it because typically in the users controller the user id is typically params[:id] rather than params[:user_id]?

Comment: parameter name is always user_id

Comment: @alex: no, the paramater is (or it should be) `param[:id]` if you are in `UsersController`.

Comment: is this user the one currently logged in? you'd use `current_user` method of your authentication library for that, not scopes.

Comment: i always pass a parameter called user_id

Comment: If there is something unique about UsersController (or its routes) then I'd update your question with both of those or else we're just playing guessing games.

Comment: I Updated the question to make clear that a parameter named user_id is always included in the request

Comment: Why not update it with what is in UsersController and its routes rather than have people guess at what might or might not be there?

Comment: updated my question - I stripped out all other code from my controller for testin so this small snipped is the full controller code!

Answer (score 1):

point.1 in UsersController, you get params[:id] as user_id

point.2 use find_by_id to avoid rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, it safely returns nil

and so...

```
def fetch_user
  user_id = controller_name=='users' ? params[:id] : params[:user_id]
  @user ||= User.find_by_id user_id
end
```

Comment: the parameter name is always user_is

Comment: you mean, you are always passing it as "user_id" ?

Comment: As per rails conventions for routes, for users controller, you get user id in params[:id], and for rest of the controllers, e.g. /users/:user_id/resources/:id, you get params[:user_id]

Comment: you may like to have a look at "rails restful routes"...it will just make your life easier  :)